# How do I use data from a rest response into ag-grid using javascript?

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I'm quite new to javascript and ag-grid and have been following what's in the tutorial to move forward.

in ag-grid's tutorial, remote data can be fetched using the code below:

```
  // fetch the row data to use and one ready provide it to the Grid via the Grid API
  agGrid.simpleHttpRequest({url: 'https://www.ag-grid.com/example-assets/row-data.json'})
      .then(data => {
          gridOptions.api.setRowData(data);
      });
```

But what if I want to use data from an api call? say the JSON response from this URI: https://api.opencritic.com/api/game/1520

Hope someone can shed some light. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform whatever transformation you need on the data before passing it to setRowData:

```js
agGrid.simpleHttpRequest( ... )
  .then(data => {

    // transform the data into whatever format you need
    const rowData = data.reduce(...) // or whatever. not _necessarily_ reduce

    gridOptions.api.setRowData(rowData);

  })
```

---

According to your comment you're getting an object `{}` instead of an array `[]` for `discounts`. I'd recommend you fix this on the API side so you get an array back to begin with, but assuming that's not possible it's trivial to convert it.

Given an object `x`, calling [Object.values(x)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) will get you an array of the, well, *values* in `x`. For example:

```js
const x = {
  foo: 'a',
  bar: 'b',
  baz: 'c',
}

const v = Object.values(x);

// v is now ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

The values can be objects too. You get back an array of objects:

```js
const x = {
  foo: { label: 'a', bang: 1 },
  bar: { label: 'b', bang: 2 },
  baz: { label: 'c', bang: 3 },
}

const v = Object.values(x);

// [{ label: 'a', bang: 1 }, { label: 'b', bang: 2 }, { label: 'c', bang: 3 }]
```

Now that you have an array, you can use array methods like [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform it:

```js
const bangs = v.map(value => value.bang);
// [1, 2, 3]
```

Note: All of these examples are using the [implicit return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#function_body) syntax for [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

If you prefer, you can use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) to tighten up the above expression. The expression below is functionally equivalent to the one above, without the repetition of "value". It doesn't make much difference in this case but it starts to add up if you need multiple fields from the input object.

```js
const bangs = v.map(({bang}) => bang);
// [1, 2, 3]
```

Destructuring also provides a mechanism for renaming a field on the way in. The example below renames `bang` to `x` and returns an object with an `x` property:

```js
// v = [{ label: 'a', bang: 1 }, { label: 'b', bang: 2 }, { label: 'c', bang: 3 }]

const bangs = v.map(({bang: x}) => ({x}));
// [{x: 1}, {x: 2}, {x: 3}]
```

You can do this shorthand destructuring/renaming with multiple fields. Here we're renaming `bang` to `x`, `label` to `y`, and returning a new object with those properties:

```js
// v = [{ label: 'a', bang: 1 }, { label: 'b', bang: 2 }, { label: 'c', bang: 3 }]

const bangs = v.map(({bang: x, label: y}) => ({x, y}));
// [{x: 1, y: 'a'}, {x: 2, y: 'b'}, {x: 3, y: 'c'}]
```

Using this approach you can remap the `BasePrice` and `SalePrice` fields in your `discounts` object to whatever format you need. In the example below I'm remapping them to an array of objects with `x` and `y` properties. I don't know that that's what agGrid expects, but tweaking it to suit your needs should be straightforward.

```js
// function that converts the sample data format to an array of
// coordinates, e.g. [{ x: 555, y: 999 }, { x: 123, y: 456 }]
function transform (input) {
  return Object.values(input.discounts)
    .map(({BasePrice: x, SalePrice: y}) => ({x, y}))
}

fakeApiRequest() // simulate the request
  .then(apiData => {
    const rowData = transform(apiData); // transform the response data
    show(rowData); // show the result
})

//-------
// everything below is just utility and convenience stuff
// for the demo. mostly irrelevant/ignorable for your purposes
//-------

// sample data
const sampleData = {
  "discounts": {
    "0": { "BasePrice": "1499", "SalePrice": "449" },
    "1": { "BasePrice": "1299", "SalePrice": "519" }
  }
}

// simulates an api request; waits a moment then resolve with sample data.
// not really relevant to your issue; just hand-waving for the demo
async function fakeApiRequest () {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(sampleData), 100)
  });
}

// irrelevant. just a convenience utility for showing the output.
function show(d) {
  document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(d, null, 3);
}
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: Hi Ray, thanks for the response. I don't think I was clear enough with my question. What I was trying to ask was, how do I declare an ag-grid request to get a response from an API? Do I still use simpleHttpRequest?

Comment: I guess I don't understand the "API" distinction you're making here. It's an http request that returns json. How is any different from the tutorial example?

Comment: I just realized that yes there was no distinction, and the reason why it was not working for me was because the tutorial example had a json file with arrays that starts with "[".

The api response I was trying to get to work is formatted like this:

`{
    "discounts":
    {
        "0":
        {
            "BasePrice": "1499",
            "SalePrice": "449",
        },
        "1":
        {
            "BasePrice": "1299",
            "SalePrice": "519",
        }
    }
}`

Any idea how can I set BasePrice, SalePrice as my row data? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much for this! My Problem was solved!